# What is the fastest collection for slicing?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need to execute the following operation:

```
collection.slice(x, y)
....
collection.slice(x+1, y+1)
...
collection.slice(x+n, y+n)
```

or

```
collection.slice(x-n, y-n)
```

Very often execution of this part of code is expected, so I want to make it as fast as possible. What collection should I choose? (can be immutable).

P.S. on [Performance Characteristics](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) page "apply" characteristic is responsible for slicing?

P.P.S looking for articles, manuals dedicated on subject.

Comment: Would an Hashtable serve your needs?

Comment: Apply is indexing. The answer very much depends on what operations _other_ than slicing you need, and what operations on slices. In particular, will you be taking slices of slices?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends somewhat on how far apart x and y are, but you are generally best off using plain arrays.  If you don't need to do anything with the slices, using views might be faster, but access is slower with views, so it's probably better to stay away from them.

Anyway, you certainly want something with fast "apply" (log or constant time), and between `Array`, `Vector`, and `ArrayBuffer`, `Array` is the fastest, `ArrayBuffer` is about 50% slower, and `Vector` is about twice as slow again for slicing and using every element that you've sliced.

Also, consider whether `sliding` will do what you want.  It's not as fast as the direct slicing, but it's awfully convenient.

Comment: > "If you don't need to do anything with the slices" you mean filtering/../mapping resulting slice before working it? Please explain.

Comment: I mean that you need them to exist but you mostly don't need to access the contents.  If you need to access the contents, it's usually faster to create a new array than it is to be redirected through a view. (Especially since views of this sort are broken right now...but even when they're fixed, you've got extra indirection.)  In general, views are good when you aren't actually going to use everything you're viewing--if you're using it all (esp. multiple times), then a copy is usually faster. If you may only use part, views are usually faster. (Not here, due to a bug, but in most cases.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Vector` has `logN` performance, though the constant factor may be too heavy depending on your requirements.

On the other hand, maybe `range` does what you want? If it does, then a `SortedMap` might well provide a `logN` performance with smaller constant factor. Maybe.

Comment: Sorted maps slice very slowly.

Comment: @Rex really? I wrote the code to fix `range` on RB trees, and it is `O(logN)`. On the other hand, a temporary fix had been committed that was `O(n)`. I wonder what's the code on 2.8.1. I assume you benchmarked it?

Comment: @Daniel - They _slice_ very slowly.  `range` is only 2x slower than `Vector` (non-view) slice, and is comparable to any `sliding` solutions if you cover the whole sequence.  (Incidentally, `slice` is almost universally broken for indexed views right now--I've submitted a ticket.)

Comment: @Rex Ah, yes. I _said_ that if `range` worked, then it could be an alternative. Such as the case where the keys are first found, and then a `slice` over the index is done -- it could have been just `range`d in first place.

Comment: @Daniel - Or you can `zipWithIndex` to get your keys and work with the values.  But it's significantly slower than a raw `slice` on the collections one would likely be tempted to use.  It is rather pathological that `range` is so much faster than `slice`...one would expect the two to have similar performance.  (Thanks for making sure at least one of them is fast!)

Comment: @Rex `range` is faster than `slice`? But you said it was 2x slower? After all, what _is_ it? As for `range`, what I did was ensuring that 1. It actually worked (the implementation was naive and broken), and 2. It worked on `O(logN)` (because, after, it could).

Comment: @Daniel - Sorry, I guess I'm not being clear.  I mean that (1) `SortedMap.slice` is incredibly, unbelievably slow; (2) `Vector.slice` is not so bad; (3) `SortedMap.range` is only modestly slower than `Vector.slice`.

Comment: @Rex It is not at all pathological that `range` is faster than `slice`. Say you have key `a`, index `i`. By checking the root of the tree, you know whether `a` is left or right of `root`, or, perhaps, `root` itself. On the other hand, you have _no idea_ whether `root` is left, right or the `i` itself.

Comment: @Daniel - Fair enough.  I was thinking of a particular architecture that makes indexing easy (i.e. those maps with `O(1)` size), but I see that it's `O(n)` for `RedBlack`.  Slice is pathologically slow _even so_, but I agree that they should be different orders for RB trees without metadata on the nodes.

Comment: @Rex Whenever I touch `RedBlack`, I'm tempted to put some metainformation on the node. However, given the impact on collection sizes, I never went for it. It would have been particularly helpful with `range`...